# ASP.Net MVC - Why is a controller being created for favicon.ico?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, favicon, static-content

I am using a custom ControllerFactory (to use Castle Windsor's IOC to create controllers), and I notice it's getting requests to create a controller for "favicon.ico". I have put a favicon.ico file in my Content folder, but I'm still getting these requests.

How do I resolve this and serve static content without trying to create controllers?

Comment: This was happening to me because browsers try to look for the favicon.ico in your root and for some reason asp.net thinks it's a controller, and it filled my logs with the error "favicon.ico controller not found", I don't know if this is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the following route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: Why not just `routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico")`?

Comment: The suggested IgnoreRoute ignores favicon.ico in any folder, not just the root. I think it comes from Phil Haack's blog (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

Comment: Oh, and it should be \. for the . in the regular expression i.e. favicon\.ico